# Connecting QGIS 3.4 to a MS Access database

Tags: qgis, database, ms-access

I try to connect to MS Access and i have already created an ODBC connection. 
Now, I have the the problem that I cannot open the database in QGIS (but the connection was succesful).
[image]

Comment: do you have the correct 64 bit (or 32 bit) drivers for the right version of access? it has changed many times by microsoft. newer access requires office 365...

Comment: I would try the 32 bit version of QGIS.